# TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

Tags: python, tornado, mysql-python

I'm trying to execute a query with the [Tornado's database wrapper](https://github.com/facebook/tornado/blob/master/tornado/database.py), like this -

```
p_id = db.execute_lastrowid("""INSERT INTO `gplaces`.`place` 
                                    (`gid`, `name`, `reference`, `lat`, `long`, `vicinity`) 
                                    VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)""", 
                                    (
                                        str(place['id']),
                                        str(place['name']),
                                        str(place['reference']),
                                        float(place['geometry']['location']['lat']),
                                        float(place['geometry']['location']['lng']),
                                        str(place['vicinity'])
                                    )
                                )
```

But always getting the error in the title. Here is the traceback -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "insertbs.py", line 38, in <module>
    str(place['vicinity'])
  File "/home/bibhas/Works/yodl/database.py", line 145, in execute_lastrowid
    self._execute(cursor, query, parameters)
  File "/home/bibhas/Works/yodl/database.py", line 207, in _execute
    return cursor.execute(query, parameters)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 159, in execute
    query = query % db.literal(args)
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't pass a tuple of values, pass them as separate arguments.

From the traceback:

```
query = query % db.literal(args)
```

Note what's being interpolated in - `args`. Basically, just remove the `()` around the things you were passing in so that they get passed as args instead.

Comment: You mean like a dictionary? Sorry if I'm sounding like a noob.

Comment: No, I mean like instead of doing `db.execute_lastrowid("query", (a,b,c))`, do `db.execute_lastrowid("query", a, b, c)`.

Comment: Got it. That worked. Thanks. :) I got confused seeing `parameters` as I thought it'll be a single variable with all the data as tuples.

Comment: how to give two or more or conditions in python sql = ("SELECT car,colour FROM tblcar WHERE size = '%s'  or size ='%s'" % search_string %search_string1) its not working for any two particular size

Answer (score 3):

Give Amber the credit, I'm just posting an example:

```
 p_id = db.execute_lastrowid("""INSERT INTO `gplaces`.`place` 
                                (`gid`, `name`, `reference`, `lat`, `long`, `vicinity`) 
                                VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)""", 

                                 str(place['id']),
                                 str(place['name']),
                                 str(place['reference']),
                                 float(place['geometry']['location']['lat']),
                                 float(place['geometry']['location']['lng']),
                                 str(place['vicinity'])

                            )
```

So, before you were only passing one argument, a tuple containing all your arguments.  In this example you are passing 6 arguments, which is what it's expecting.